# How to calculate 50Hz active power measurement accuracy from datasheet?

Tags: power, datasheet, accuracy, power-measurement

The R&S [HMC8015 power analyzer datasheet](https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_common_library/dl_brochures_and_datasheets/pdf_1/service_support_30/HMC8015_bro_en_3607-3374-12_v0101.pdf#page8) and [technical data](https://static.eleshop.nl/mage/media/wysiwyg/downloads/R&S/HMC8015_um.pdf#page39) list:

### Range configuration

```
            CF3      Peak
voltage     600 V    ±1800 V
current     100 mA   ±300 mA
```

### Measurement accuracy (±reading in % ±peak range in %)

```
Frequency         ActivePower   
45Hz < f < 66Hz   0.05 + 0.05
```

voltage, current: F = frequency in kHz

#### Additional errors

Power factor < 1 | ±(0.2 + 0.2 *F)%, only for active power

---

Does this mean that when range is set to 600 V, 100 mA and measuring these values:

- Urms = 229.96 V
- f    = 49.986 Hz
- Irms = 15.33 mA (with peaks to 230mA)
- P = 0.064 W
- Q = 3.525 var
- Lambda = 0.018

That the **measurement accuracy for active power** can be calculated as follows:

1. 0.05% for reading + 0.2% for power factor < 1 = 0.25% of reading

plus

2. 0.05% for peak range + 0.2*F for power factor < 1 = 0.05 + 0.2 * 0.049986 ≅ 0.06% of peak value for range

resulting in a nett measurement accuracy of:

1. 0.06% of 0.064 W = 0.0000384 W

plus

2. 1800 V x 0.3 A = 600 * 0.06% = 0.36 W

totalling to ≅ ±0.36 W of measurement accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohde & Schwarz Vertriebs GmbH does confirm that the accuracy calculation in the question above — of plus or minus 360 milliwatts for range 600V, 100mA at 50Hz — **is correct** for power factors below 1.